# Can print SageMath logo as text in LaTeX?

Tags: sagetex

I know we could use `\LaTeX{}` to print its logo in text in LaTeX. I wonder whether we can do the same thing for SageMath?

Comment: Like this https://texwelt.de/fragen/17958/wie-schreibe-ich-das-sage-logo?

Comment: @user187803, thanks for the link. A bit surprising for a germen solution.